# how to string convert to number totalseconds?

Tags: javascript

```
{
    time : string = "00:01:30";
    console.log("i want 90");
}

//my c# code 

Timespan mytime;
System.Convert.ToInt32(mytime.TotalSeconds);
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
{
    time : string = "00:01:30";
    console.log("i want 90");
}

//my c# code 

Timespan mytime;
System.Convert.ToInt32(mytime.TotalSeconds);
```

how get totalseconds?

i want return number -> 90

not date() type

string type parameter -> totalseconds

string time convert number totalseconds

how to string convert to number totalseconds?

Comment: Split by colons and multiply by 3600 and 60 respectively? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are. It does validate the input string, so e.g. `a:20:30` returns false, as well as `0:0:12` does. The only correct format is `HH:MM:SS`

```
function stringToSec(string){
    var format = /^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
    if(!format.test(string)) return false;
    var h = parseInt(string.substr(0,2));
    var m = parseInt(string.substr(3,2));
    var s = parseInt(string.substr(6,2));
    return h * 3600 + m * 60 + s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split, reverse, map, then sum in order to figure out the answer:

```js
const getSeconds = inputString => inputString
  .split(':')
  .reverse()
  .map((x, i) => Math.pow(60, i) * parseInt(x))
  .reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0)
  
const result = getSeconds("00:01:30")

console.dir(result)
```